# ¿Cómo limitar la "accion" de un break?

Tags: c++

Mi pregunta se basa en saber si existe alguna manera de limitar el efecto que produce **break** en el código, específicamente para que detenga un  bucle y no todos.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
              //[i,x][j,z]
typedef int Sudoku[3][3];

int main(){
    int a,b = 0;
    Sudoku s = {1,1,3,1,5,6,5,7,9};

    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3;j++){
        a = s[i][j];

            for(int x = 0;x < 3;x++){
                if(x == i)continue;
                if(a == s[x][j])b = 1;break;//aquí es el "problema"
            }
            for(int z = 0;z < 3;z++){
                if(z == j)continue;
                if(a == s[i][z])b = 2;break;
            }

        }
    }

    if(b == 1)cout<<"error en columna"<<endl;
    if(b == 2)cout<<"error en fila"<<endl;

    for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++){
        if(i%3 == 0) cout <<"---------"<<endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3;j++){
            if(j%3 == 0) cout<< "| ";
            cout<<s[i][j]<<' ';
        }
        cout<<"|"<<endl;
    }
    cout <<"---------"<<endl;
}
```

Se que la solución mas simple es eliminar el **break** y dejar que el código siga su curso, pero la idea es saber si existe otra opción.

**ACTUALIZACION**: he aplicado lo que me han enseñado y despues de una optimizacion de el codigo ha quedado esto: http://cpp.sh/82cq6

Comment: Quizás no entiendo muy bien lo que intentas hacer con el código, pero te diría que faltan unas cuantas llaves para envolver los `break` con los `if`; si no, el `break` se ejecutará siempre en la primera iteración de cada uno de los dos bucles, ¿no?

Comment: La pregunta no es nada clara. Bassily, ¿podrías aportar más información? Un saludo.

Comment: @MiquelColi no veo cómo la pregunta no puede ser clara: _Es posible usar **break** para salir de un bucle sin salir de los bucles padres_ dicho de otra forma. Quizá si necesita un poco de corrección o transformar el código en algo más simple para enfocarse en el problema, pero creo que la pregunta no entra en la clasificación de *No es para nada clara*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El break por definicion afecta al bucle más próximo. Por lo tanto un break solo afectará a un bucle y no todos.

[Aqui tienes documentación sobre el break.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/37zc9d2w.aspx)

Por otro lado como dice @AlvaroMontoro en un comentario, es posible que te hayas equivocado en los breaks de los bucles interiores por no poner llaves al if. 
Los has puesto así (te pongo las llaves para que te quede claro) y dudo que es lo que quisieras:

```
for(int x = 0;x < 3;x++){
    if(x == i){
         continue;
    }
    if(a == s[x][j]){
          b = 1;
    }
    break;//aquí es el "problema"
}
for(int z = 0;z < 3;z++){
    if(z == j){
         continue;
    }
    if(a == s[i][z]){
         b = 2;
    }
    break;
}
```

Lo que yo creo que tu querías y con lo que te refieres de limitar el break es esto:

```
for(int x = 0;x < 3;x++){
    if(x == i){
         continue;
    }
    if(a == s[x][j]){
          b = 1;
          break;
    }
}
for(int z = 0;z < 3;z++){
    if(z == j){
         continue;
    }
    if(a == s[i][z]){
         b = 2;
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: EXACTO!!!. eso es lo que queria lograr.

Answer (score 6):

Según el [estándar C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (la traducción y el resaltado es mío):

> #### § 6.6.1 la instrucción `break`
>
> 1. La instrucción `break` debe aparecer sólo en una instrucción de iteración o una instrucción `switch` y **causará la finalización de la instrucción de iteración más pequeña y anidada** o la instrucción `switch`; el control pasa a la instrucción posterior a la instrucción finalizada, si hay alguna.
>
> #### § 6.6.2 la instrucción `continue`
>
> 1. La instrucción `continue` debe aparecer sólo en una instrucción de iteración y provocará que el control salte hasta la sección de continuación del bucle de la instrucción de iteración más pequeña, esto es, al final del bucle. Concretamente, en cada una de las instrucciones:
>
>    ```
>    while (foo) {            do {            for (; ;) {
>     {                         {                {
>       // ...                    // ...           // ...
>     }                         }                }
>     contin: ;                contin: ;       contin: ;
>    }                        }               }
>    ```
>
> Una instrucción `continue` fuera de una instrucción de iteración es equivalente a `goto contin`.

Suele ser difícil de interpretar el estándar, y al traducir puedo haber cometido errores que modifiquen el significado, pero viene a decir que una instrucción `break` sólo *rompe* el bucle en que se encuentra (tal y como comenta [Daniel Faro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16500/2742)). Así que en tu código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {       // Bucle 1
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   // Bucle 1.1
    a = s[i][j];

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) { // Bucle 1.1.1
            if (x == i) continue;
            if (a == s[x][j]) b = 1; break; //aquí es el "problema"
        }
        for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) { // Bucle 1.1.2
            if (z == j) continue;
            if (a == s[i][z])b = 2; break;
        }
    }
}
```

El primer `break` sale del `Bucle 1.1.1` e inicia el `Bucle 1.1.2`. El segundo `break` sale del `Bucle 1.1.2` e inicia la siguiente vuelta del `Bucle 1.1`. Lo curioso es que como ya ha comentado [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) en los comentarios, la instrucción `break` **sucede a cada vuelta de los Bucles** `1.1.1` y `1.1.2` porque no está englobada en la condición.

Es decir: tus Bucles `1.1.1` y `1.1.2` **sólo dan una vuelta** antes de interrumpirse.

#### Respuesta

Una posible solución es la que ya ha propuesto [Daniel Faro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16500/2742), que consiste básicamente en corregir las llaves de tus instrucciones `if`. Otra es aprovechar la estructura de los bucles `for`:

```
for ( instrucción-de-inicialización; condición; expresión) instrucción
```

La sección *condición* evalúa si el bucle debe seguir rodando, esta condición puede ser cualquier instrucción cuyo resultado sea booleano (verdadero o falso) o convertible a booleano. Así pues, en tu caso, podríamos reescribir tus bucles de la siguiente manera:

```
// Bucle 1
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    // Bucle 1.1
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    a = s[i][j];

        // Bucle 1.1.1
        for (int x = 0; (x < 3) && !b; ++x) {
            if (x == i) continue;
            if (a == s[x][j]) b = 1;
        }
        // Bucle 1.1.2
        for (int z = 0; (z < 3) && !b; ++z) {
            if (z == j) continue;
            if (a == s[i][z]) b = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Al estar `b` inicializada a `0`, cuando en el `Bucle 1.1.1` se detecte un error, éste dejará de rodar al evaluar la condición `(x < 3) && !b` como falsa, ya que `b` es un entero, cuyo valor se transforma a `true` para cualquier valor diferente a `0`; así que la condición se podría interpretar como "*mientras `x` sea menor a `3` y no haya ningún error*". Si se detecta un error (`b` es diferente de `0`) ya no se rodará el `Bucle 1.1.2` ahorrandote hacer operaciones sobre un conjunto de datos que ya se sabe que es erróneo.

Comment: Adoro tus respuestas, +5.

Comment: @NaCl la respuesta que responde exáctamente lo que pide bassily no es la mía, pero consideré importante mencionar todas las cosas que escribí, gracias por apreciarlo :)